# Question based on operator precedence in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-precedence

```
str = 'Welcome to the Jungle'
count = 0
for i in str:
    if i=='a' or i=='e' not in i=='l' or i=='o' or i=='u':
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Using the precedence order given on https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-operator-precedence/ , `==`  and `not in` operators have the same precedence so I must go from left to right. According to that logic, since `i=='e'` evaluates to False for the `i=0` that is the first letter `W`. So, we have `False not in i`(not in should be evaluated first according to left to right order) which would equate to `True` for all letters in `str` except `i='e'`. But, the python interpreter gives the value of `count` as 3 which is much less than what should come according to my logic.

Can someone please explain how to solve this problem? This is my first question on StackOverflow, so I apologize if I've written the question in wrong formatting.

Thank You.

Comment: what is the `not in` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Sayse That's what I don't understand, I don't get the point of 'not in'  here. But this is the question, and it isn't giving any error.

Comment: Because of the operator precedence you mentioned, you are evaluating `((i=='e') not in i)=='l'`. `not in` returns a boolean, which will never be equal to `'l'`.

Comment: @thshea Yeah, but that is the correct precedence, right? So I don't get what's wrong with my logic.

Comment: "So, we have 'False not in i' which would equate to True for all letters in `str` except `i='e'`"

But then you test if that result is equal to `'l'`. Which a boolean will never be. So that statement will always evaluate to false.

Comment: Somehow, I feel this is a `XY problem`? Please don't use Python built-in `str` as variable name next time.

Comment: @DanielHao Sorry, it was just a question someone gave to me, I'll take care of it next time.

Comment: @thshea But don't all strings except empty string evaluate to Truthy? And even if they aren't equal for True or False, then the whole thing inside 'if' would never evaluate to True and the output should be count = 0. But the answer shown by the interpreter is count = 3

Comment: If you run `True == "l"` you get false. If you were to run `True == bool("l")` you would get true. As for your second point, your `or` statements still let the overall condition be true if the letter is a, o, or u.

Comment: @thshea Okay, I got your logic. But still, then the output value of count should be 2, because 'a' isn't found in the string.

Comment: This code involves *chained comparisons*, a unique Python feature - you can't understand it solely in terms of operator precedence.  It's the same thing that allows you to write range comparisons such as `0 < x < 100`.

Comment: There are two `o`s and one `u`...it should be three.

Comment: @jasonharper It would be really helpful if you could elaborate on this.

Answer (score 0):

@SaumilSood - you have asked `how to solve this problem` - I will assume you're interested in finding out how many `vowels` in the sentence in the Pythonic way, if yes, you could try this:

```py
s = 'Welcome to the Jungle'
>>> vowels = 'aeiou'
>>> sum(1 for c in s if c in vowels)
7
```

Comment: But that is a totally different problem, I know how to solve this vowel problem.

Comment: Well, then please just ignore it.  That's why I said `I will assume` .... No problem.